# Styled components React router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

```
const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  text-decoration: ${(props) => {
    console.log(props.style);
    return props.style ? (isActive) => (isActive ? "underline" : "none") : "none";
  }};
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`;

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar>
        <NavItems>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink
              to="/"
              end={true}
              style={({ isActive }) => {
                console.log(isActive + "About");
                return { textDecoration: isActive ? "underline" : "none" };
              }}
            >
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink
              to="/about"
              style={({ isActive }) => {
                console.log(isActive + "About");
                return { textDecoration: isActive ? "underline" : "none" };
              }}
            >
              About
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink
              to="/dashboard"
              style={({ isActive }) => {
                console.log(isActive + "Dashboard");
                return { textDecoration: isActive ? "underline" : "none" };
              }}
            >
              Dashboard
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </NavItems>
      </Navbar>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" caseSensitive={false} element={<Home />}></Route>
        <Route path="/about" caseSensitive={false} element={<About />}></Route>
        <Route path="/dashboard" caseSensitive={false} element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

How can I abstract out the logic for styling an active link to say the StyledNavLink styled component, I tried using StyledNavLink in place of Navlink but it doesn't work. I'm not sure what I might be missing.
If I console out props.style within the StyledNavLink then it is always undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  text-decoration: ${(props) => {
    console.log(props.style);
    return props.style ? (isActive) => (isActive ? "underline" : "none") : "none";
  }};
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
 &[aria-current] {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

I just had to check if aria-current attribute was present and now if I replace NavLink with StyledNavLink every thing works as expected

Or, as shown below, one can check for existence of the active class

```
const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
    text-decoration: ${(props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return props.style ? (isActive) => (isActive ? "underline" : "none") : "none";
  }}; 
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
 &[class*="active"] {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

*I am not so sure about this, but similar problem I have faced while styling `Link` of `NextJS` using `styled-components`. So maybe that can also work here.*

---

##### Workaround

You can create a `LinkWrapper` styled component which wrap the link with any default component like `div`, `span`, etc, which does not create any other issue to what you are trying to do, and then style the `Navlik` which in reality will become an `a` tag, so you can nested style the `a` tag (`NavLink`) using that `LinkWrapper`.

```
const LinkWrapper= styled.div`
  a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: ${props => props.propToPass ? 'flex-start' : 'center'};
    align-items: center;
  }
`;

function App(props) {
  return(
    <LinkWrapper propToPass={/**/}>
      <Link to={props.link}>
        {props.name}
      </Link>
    </LinkWrapper>
  );
}
```

**Try this, I think this can be a solution**